# codeIgniter assign parser result to variable

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

In CI, we all know that you can assign the view into a variable like:

```
$a = $this->load->view('theview',$data,true);
```

Is this possible to parser function like this:

```
$a = $this->parser->parse('thetemplate',$data,true);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yea, this works:

```
$string = $this->parser->parse('thetemplate', $data, TRUE);
```

the `TRUE` at end avoids it to be sent to the output class

See: [CI Parser](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/parser.html)

Comment: Yes it is working now. Some syntax error in passing data and library spelling. All I thought this is invalid because its not working on my end while ago. anyway, thank you.